# Move search bar to right hand side of navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to move my search bar to far right of my navbar. I have reviewed other questions but not fixes seem to work for me.

Some help identifying why would be great.

**navbar html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'home' %}"
        >Home</a
      >
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'gallery' %}">Gallery</a>
      <a class="navbar-name" href="{% url 'home' %}">MARTIN HENSON PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
      <form class="d-flex" method="POST" action="{% url 'searchblogs' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Search keyword" name="searched">
        <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary-outline rounded-0">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**navbar css**

```
  .navbar {
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-name {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an easy fix. Just add a float right CSS to your search bar:

```css
  .navbar {
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-name {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
    .d-flex {
        float:right;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'home' %}"
        >Home</a
      >
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'gallery' %}">Gallery</a>
      <a class="navbar-name" href="{% url 'home' %}">MARTIN HENSON PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
      <form class="d-flex" method="POST" action="{% url 'searchblogs' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Search keyword" name="searched">
        <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary-outline rounded-0">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**If you run the snippet, make sure you click "full page" to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any styles for `navbar-nav`. It is a problem, because in row are just inline elements a that's why is form under it. You need to add `d-flex`.

```
<div class="navbar-nav d-flex">
```

and use something for justify elements for spacings see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.